# How to calculate ip address in a range?

Tags: ip, ip-address, scanning

If I run this command,

# nmap -sP 192.168.0.120/25

which IP addresses are scanned?

How can I calculate the IP addresses that are in this range? I've been searching Google but I couldn't find something helpful.

Answer (score 4):

There is a useful utility, in Linux, called ipcalc. If it is not installed by default, you may download it from your distro's repositories. In Mac OS, you can find the same utility [here](http://download.cnet.com/IPCalc/3000-18508_4-43834.html), while for Windows you find it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipcalc-net/) (careful with dependencies, it requires Microsoft .Network Framework 2.0).

Its output is like this, exactly for your case:

```
 ipcalc 192.168.0.120/25
 Address:   192.168.0.120        11000000.10101000.00000000.0 1111000
 Netmask:   255.255.255.128 = 25 11111111.11111111.11111111.1 0000000
 Wildcard:  0.0.0.127            00000000.00000000.00000000.0 1111111
 =>
 Network:   192.168.0.0/25       11000000.10101000.00000000.0 0000000
 HostMin:   192.168.0.1          11000000.10101000.00000000.0 0000001
 HostMax:   192.168.0.126        11000000.10101000.00000000.0 1111110
 Broadcast: 192.168.0.127        11000000.10101000.00000000.0 1111111
 Hosts/Net: 126                   Class C, Private Internet
```

Comment: Does this mean that the ip addresses scanned are from 192.168.0.1-- 192.168.0.126? Or from .120-.126? I am a little bit confused...

Comment: Note that you can simply use `nmap` to answer this question by running `nmap -n -sL 192.168.0.120/25`.  The first valid host address is 192.168.0.1; the ".0" address for a network is not a valid host address.

Answer (score 0):

Enter "25" in the "Mask Bits" field and it will show all the details for the network:  http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php